# VB.Net MenuStrip - All submenus visible at once

Tags: vb.net, menustrip

Weird question:

I have a menustrip in a VB.Net windows form, my teacher in the university said that if I could make all dropdowns of the menustrip become visible at once, he would release me from the exam :D

Is this even possible and how?

I know I can `.ShowDropDown()` an entry, but when I call the next, the first one hides.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your teacher is not helping you spend your time wisely.  Do the exam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this can help:

CType(MenuStrip1.Items(0), ToolStripDropDownItem).DropDown.AutoClose = False

CType(MenuStrip1.Items(1), ToolStripDropDownItem).DropDown.AutoClose = False

CType(MenuStrip1.Items(0), ToolStripDropDownItem).ShowDropDown()

CType(MenuStrip1.Items(1), ToolStripDropDownItem).ShowDropDown()

In my test I get the two DropDown inside the ToolStripDropDownItems opened at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Bear in mind that often what is possible is not what is desirable.

Users of Windows expect programs to behave in certain standard ways and to be laid out following the various style and design guidelines promoted by Microsoft.

When your program breaks those guidelines users become confused and annoyed.

Interface design is important and your teacher is hopefully trying to get you to think about this area. The professional answer would be that although it is possible to have all the drop downs open at once it would be an unpleasant experience for the user.